# Can I remove a toolbar title present on the Windows 7 taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar, toolbar

I use the `Address` toolbar on the windows 7 taskbar using the following shortcut:

[image: Add toolbar]

Is it possible to remove the title of the toolbar displayed in front of the address box?

[image: Address title]

This is just taking space on my taskbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, simply unlock the taskbar, right-click the toolbar and uncheck **Show title**.  The option doesn't show if the taskbar is locked.